# Очень сильно лагает и зависает эмулятор Android

Tags: android, android-sdk, android-emulator

Настройки эмулятора на скриншоте

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]У меня есть программа "Android SDK and AVD Manager". Скачал, создал эмулятор Android 3.2, но при запуске он очень сильно лагает и зависает, и почти невозможно работать. Можно ли как-то это исправить?
Эмулятор Android полностью завис. Работает только нижняя панель с уведомлениями, остальными функциями пользоваться невозможно.
Можно ли исправить это?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Попробуйте x86 образ, а не arm.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, у вас мало свободной памяти на диске, на котором установлен эмулятор.
Это можно исправить, если перенести эмулятор на диск, на котором много места.

Для этого нужно перенести на большой диск папку .android из стандартной папки "C:\Users\Пользователь" в новую папку.

Далее нужно изменить переменную ANDROID_SDK_HOME, указав папку, в которой теперь находится .android.

Comment: у меня свободно 31 ГБ на диске С. Эмуляторы Android 2.0-2.3 и выше кроме 3.0 работают нормально. А 3.0 лагает. Может у меня неправильные настройки эмулятора?